# Definition of the $L^2$-metric for the Determinant of Cohomology of a Vector Bundle on a Riemann surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, at.algebraic-topology

I start describing my setup. $X$ is a Riemann surface with a metric which can have a finite number of singularities, $E$ is a vector bundle on $X$ equipped with an Hermitian structure.

In an article (PhD-thesis) I´m reading it is used the notion of $L^2$-metric on $\lambda(E)$, the determinant of cohomology of $E$.

I don´t see how to arrange the standard argument for defining the $L^2$-metric works in this case. The standard argument, which requires the metric on $X$ to be Kähler, should be the following. Take a Dolbeault resolution for $E$ on $X$, then by Hodge theory we have the isomorphism:

$H^q(X,E)\simeq Ker(\Delta^q),$

where $\Delta^q$ is the (Hodge) Laplacian acting on the space of $(0,q)$-forms $A^{(0,q)}(X,E)$. Since $A^{(0,q)}(X,E)\simeq \mathcal{C}^\infty(X,E\otimes\bigwedge_q T_X^*)$, and $E$ and $T_X$ are equipped with hermitian structures (*here I´m using the metric on $X$ being Kähler*) we deduce the standard $L^2$ metric on $\mathcal{C}^\infty(X,E\otimes\bigwedge_q T_X^*)$. 
Which restricts to $Ker\Delta^q$ and finally to $H^q(X,E)$. Taking duals and tensor products one gets a metric on the whole $\lambda(E)$.

So my question is: how can I define such an $L^2$-metric when my starting metric is no longer Kähler?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Any metric on a Riemann surface is Kahler, so you are in the situation you know. Even if you weren't, I don't think you need the metric on $X$ to be Kahler to get an $L^2$ metric. Just use the $\Delta'' = \bar \partial \bar \partial^* + \bar \partial^* \bar \partial$ Laplacian to define harmonic forms, then proceed as usual. What might get messy if the metric is not Kahler is deducing any kind of curvature properties of the induced metric, for example to annihilate cohomology groups via a Bochner-Kodaira-Nakano argument.

Comment: Is the the bundle $E$ is equipped with a connection $A$? If so,  you could use the Laplacian $\Delta_A$ on smooth forms. This makes sense on any Riemannian manifold, and any bundle $E$ with connection.
 

Comment: @Gunnar, Thank you for the response. I hope I´m not messing things. As far as I know every *Riemannian* metric on a Riemann surface is Kähler, and I need it to be positive definite. The leading example is the Riemann surface $\Gamma \ \mathbb{H}$ where $\Gamma\subset SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ has parabolic elements and $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half plane with the hyperbolic metric. Then the quotient is a Riemann surface with cusps and the limit of the hyperbolic metric to the cusps is zero. In specific, taking the compactification of the Riemann surface, the metric is not positive definite anymore.

Comment: (I cannot edit comments, but the RS above is the quotient of $\mathbb{H}$ by the action of $\Gamma$). The question was not precise because also the Hodge isomorphism requires the metric on $X$ to be Kähler to hold, I edited it now. This means that also if I can define the Laplacian as you suggest I don´t know how to relate $H^q(X,E)$ to the world of $(p,q)$-forms. Does it make sense what I´m saying? Thank you again!

Comment: @Paul, I don´t think it has one, in the sense that in the setup $E$ has nothing more than an Hermitian structure, and I don´t see how it can define a connection. Moreover there is the problem of the positive definiteness of the metric I sketched in the comments above, that would imply that we are *not* on a Riemannian manifold. But maybe I´m just saying rubbish. Thank you too for your interest!


Comment: Do you know that $L^{2}$-index theorem?